# Syntax error with a limit clause

Tags: mysql

I have this routine working in dev, I went to copy it into production and I get a "check your syntax near...' error on the Update line. It saves if I take out the limit clause.

Like I say, this is working in Dev. Copy and pasted the structure def, so I know it's identical.

```
 DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `SQS_Get_Messages`(IN queue_requested INT, IN queue_limit INT)
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    DECLARE my_uuid INT;
    DECLARE fake INT;
    DECLARE now DATETIME;

    SELECT Get_Lock('message_get',10) INTO fake;

    SELECT NOW() INTO now;  
    SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP()+mod(UUID_SHORT(),1000) INTO my_uuid;

    UPDATE sqs SET `status`= my_uuid, `started_timestamp` = now WHERE `status` = 0 and `queue` = queue_requested LIMIT queue_limit; 

    SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('message_get') INTO fake;
    SELECT `id`,`body`,`status` from sqs WHERE `status` = my_uuid; 

END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works in dev, but fails with a copy and paste into production, you have a version mismatch between your dev server and your production server, or you've failed to copy and paste properly. There aren't any other explanations that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

that was it, the new database is running a slightly older version of MySQL. Thanks Ken. (I have insufficient 'points' to properly reward you, but you have my gratitude. :-) )

Comment: Thanks. I tried to up-vote it but don't have the 'points'.